# Google Sheets API json files - What is the difference between CLIENT_SECRET and oauth2client credentials?

Tags: python, json, api, credentials, google-sheets-api

I followed the Google Sheet Python API Quickstart guide (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) and was able to get it working using their supplied code:

```
def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """

    # If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    # at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'my/path/client_secret.json'
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python Quickstart'

    credential_path = 'my/path/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json'

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()

    ## !!!!! Is this needed?
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)

    return credentials
```

In the default setup I downloaded two JSON files:

- `client_secret.JSON`

  - downloaded to `project` directory.
- `sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.JSON`

  - downloaded to `~/.credentials` directory

The `sheets.googleapis.com` JSON file starts with:

```
"_module": "oauth2client.client".
```

**Question 1:** What is the purpose for each of these JSON files?

**Question 2:** Are both of these JSON files needed to successfully use the Google Sheets API?

- I am thinking no, as I am able to get the API working without the `client_secret.JSON` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer? I think when you know the OAuth2 process for retrieving access token and refresh token, you can understand the meaning of both files. The flow for retrieving access token and refresh token using OAuth2 is as follows.

### Flow :

1. Download `client_secret.JSON` from the API Console.

   - `client_secret.JSON` includes `client_id`, `client_secret` and `redirect_uris`.
2. Retrieve an authorization code using scopes and `client_id` from `client_secret.JSON`.
3. Retrieve access token and refresh token using the authorization code, `client_id`, `client_secret` and `redirect_uris`.

   - Retrieved access token, refresh token and other parameters are saved to the file of `sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.JSON`.

### Note :

- When you run the Quickstart **for the first time**, the authorization process using your browser is launched. At that time, the script of Quickstart retrieves the authorization code using `client_id` and scopes, and then the access token and refresh token are retrieved using the authorization code, `client_id`, `client_secret` and `redirect_uris`.
- **After the first run** of the Quickstart, the access token is retrieved by the refresh token from `sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.JSON`. By this, retrieving the authorization code using browser is not required to do. So when there is `sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.JSON`, `client_secret.JSON` is not required.

  - I think that this leads to an answer for your Question 2.
- But, if you want to change scopes and/or credentials of `client_secret.JSON`, the authorization process using browser and retrieving the authorization code are required to do. For this, you have to remove `sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.JSON` and authorize again. At that time, at Quickstart, `client_secret.JSON` is used again.

### References :

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)
- [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)

If this is not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Very helpful. My understanding is that if I want to run my app on another computer, I would only need to send over my 'client_secret.json' file, as that file alone would allow me to generate a new 'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.JSON' file on a new computer that doesn't have that file already. Is that correct?

Comment: is there a reason I shouldn't just save the sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.JSON file in my project directory on the same level as client_secret.json? AKA: is there a reason I need to set up this logic to generate it after I have it once?

Comment: @ben You can put ``client_secret.json`` in the directory you want. But please set the path in the script. It is read when the refresh token is retrieved. So when you already have the refresh token, it is not used for running script.